# Publish from VSO to Azure - Unable to locate Dependency

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When i try to deploy my successfully build project to azure website it says:

Complete Deployment Log

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling ASP.NET 5 Web Application deployment.
'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1' is already installed in D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1.
Adding D:\local\UserProfile\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1\bin to process PATH
Microsoft .NET Development Utility Clr-x86-1.0.0-rc1-16231

    CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\packages\EntityFramework.Commands\7.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.hosting.abstractions/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.sources/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.platformabstractions/index.json
    NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.commandlineutils.sources/index.json 565ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.platformabstractions/index.json 787ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnet.hosting.abstractions/index.json 829ms
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.console/index.json
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.console/index.json 129ms
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-*
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\packages\EntityFramework.Commands\7.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 7466ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor\1.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/index.json
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.runtime/index.json 623ms
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor\1.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 2299ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost\1.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.tracesource/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.primitives/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.sockets/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.extensions/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.typeextensions/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading.thread/index.json
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.process/index.json 428ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.tracesource/index.json 428ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener/index.json 499ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.sockets/index.json 688ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.primitives/index.json 712ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.threading.thread/index.json 709ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.extensions/index.json 813ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.reflection.typeextensions/index.json 812ms
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Dnx.TestHost\1.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 3682ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Api\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Api\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 14786ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Data\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Data\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 7904ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Models\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Models\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 1068ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Web\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Web\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 22986ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\test\ShiftScheduler.Tests\project.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.dnx/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.visualstudio/index.json
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.visualstudio/index.json 1452ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.dnx/index.json 2098ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit/index.json 2371ms
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\test\ShiftScheduler.Tests\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 21737ms elapsed

Total time 107990ms
Errors in D:\home\site\repository\packages\EntityFramework.Commands\7.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json

    Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-*
Feeds used:
    https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-*\r\n\r\nErrors in D:\home\site\repository\packages\EntityFramework.Commands\7.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json\r\n    Unable to locate Dependency Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.Sources >= 1.0.0-*\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\53.50321.2147\bin\scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Is this a temporarly problem?

Anybody else has a solution?

Comment: How do your deploy it? And can you share the entire logs? I just tried to deploy an asp.net core project to Azure by the steps here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/deploy-aspnet5 but didn't see any issues. The deployment can be finished successfully.

Comment: Updated the log. Once i tried the link you mentioned. This had worked. But now im always facing my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the logs, you are using Kudu service to deploy the project from Git repo. And base on following entries:

```
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\packages\EntityFramework.Commands\7.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor\1.0.0-rc1-final\app\project.json
```

The "packages" folder has been pushed to Kudu remote repository. The deployment is trying to restore the "project.json" file in "packages" folder which cause the issue. Generally, the deployment should only restore the "project.json" file for your project. And according to the logs, there wasn't any issue with it:

```
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Api\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Api\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 14786ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Data\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Data\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 7904ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Models\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Models\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 1068ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Web\project.json
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\src\ShiftScheduler.Web\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 22986ms elapsed
Restoring packages for D:\home\site\repository\test\ShiftScheduler.Tests\project.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.dnx/index.json
    GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.visualstudio/index.json
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.visualstudio/index.json 1452ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit.runner.dnx/index.json 2098ms
    OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/xunit/index.json 2371ms
Writing lock file D:\home\site\repository\test\ShiftScheduler.Tests\project.lock.json
Restore complete, 21737ms elapsed
```

By default, the dnx packages are restored to %userprofile%.dnx\packages% or %$HOME/.dnx/packages% folder. I'm not sure if you had do anything to change this but you need to check it. Or you can also update the .gitignore file of the repository to exclude the "packages" folder. After done this, go to Kudu webportal "https://webappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole" and then select "Debug Console", delete "packages" folder in "D:\home\site\repository\" and then try to deploy again.

Comment: I guess there have been many issues on my website. (e.g. in my Test project). Thanks for point some things out. I started looking at the Kudo Web Portal. That helped me a lot!. You help is highly appreciated!